# How to query data from nested document in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, document-database

I'm struggling with this nested document too much. I tried to read the document and also follow other SO responses to see if it works for me, but I'm not getting the results that I'm looking for. I want to extract some information from a big nested document.

**DATA**

I've uploaded the data to mongo playground. https://mongoplayground.net/p/7nbLtXMlFMx

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5f7f29259ac5883ec5eed1ec"},"name":"Walmart","page":{"name":"body","config":{},"children":[{"name":"company-title","config":{"title":"Walmart","rank":"1","franchiseTitle":"Fortune 500","franchisePermalink":"https://fortune.com/fortune500/2020/","parentPermalink":"https://fortune.com/company/walmart/"},"children":[]},{"name":"company-single-pagination","config":{"prevName":"","prevLink":"","prevRank":"","nextName":"Amazon.com","nextLink":"https://fortune.com/company/amazon-com/fortune500/","nextRank":2,"hideRanking":false,"rank":"1","franchiseTitle":"Fortune 500"},"children":[]},{"name":"company-hero","config":{"description":"After years of investment in its technology and stores, Walmart has indisputably emerged as a strong No. 2 to Amazon in U.S. e-commerce, with sales up 37% last year. But as the initial weeks of the novel coronavirus pandemic have shown, Walmart’s 4,600 U.S. stores have proved to be an effective weapon by allowing curbside pickup for online orders at a time shoppers want to limit time in stores—but still want their orders quickly. That sentiment is not likely to change anytime soon. Walmart Inc.’s Sam’s Club is finding renewed energy, too. Walmart is benefiting from focusing on select overseas markets, such as India and China, rather than competing everywhere."},"children":[{"name":"brightcove-video","config":{"accountId":"2111767321001","disableAds":false,"disableAutoplay":false,"disableContinuousPlay":false,"disableViewplay":false,"isLeadVideo":false,"loop":false,"playerId":"HDNR3TkSj","stickyPlayerOff":false,"silentlyAutoplay":true,"videoId":{"$numberLong":"6156999393001"},"section":""},"children":[]}]},{"name":"company-about-wrapper","config":{},"children":[{"name":"company-additional-media","config":{},"children":[]},{"name":"advertising-slot","config":{"align":"center","lazyload":true,"useDynamicChannel":true,"placementName":"InStream","slotId":"InStream0","targeting":{"placement_name":"InStream","index":1}},"children":[]},{"name":"company-information","config":{"title":"Company information","country":"U.S.","headquarters":"Bentonville, Ark.","industry":"General Merchandise","ceo":"C. Douglas McMillon","website":"https://www.stock.walmart.com","companyType":"Public","ticker":"WMT","revenues":"523964","profits":"14881","marketValue":"389244","employees":"2200000","updated":"9/21/20","footnote":"Market value as of Sept. 15, 2020."},"children":[]},{"name":"advertising-slot","config":{"align":"center","lazyload":true,"useDynamicChannel":true,"placementName":"InStream","slotId":"InStream1","targeting":{"placement_name":"InStream","index":2}},"children":[]},{"name":"company-information","config":{"title":"Company information","country":"U.S.","headquarters":"Bentonville, Ark.","industry":"General Merchandise","ceo":"C. Douglas McMillon","website":"https://www.stock.walmart.com","companyType":"Public","ticker":"WMT","revenues":"523964","profits":"14881","marketValue":"389244","employees":"2200000","updated":"9/21/20","footnote":"Market value as of Sept. 15, 2020."},"children":[]},{"name":"company-table-wrapper","config":{},"children":[{"name":"company-data-table","config":{"title":"Key Financials (Last Fiscal Year)","tableIndex":0,"table":{"franchiseId":2814606,"title":"Key Financials (Last Fiscal Year)","rows":[{"value":"Revenues ($M)","pctChange":"Revenue Percent Change"},{"value":"Profits ($M)","pctChange":"Profits Percent Change"},{"value":"Assets ($M)"},{"value":"Total Stockholder Equity ($M)"}],"showValue":"show_value","valueHeader":"$ millions","showPctChange":"show_pct_change","pctChangeHeader":"% change"},"updated":"","data":[{"key":"f500_revenues","value":"523964","fieldMeta":{"franchiseId":2814606,"title":"Revenues ($M)","altTitle":"Revenues ($M)","description":"Companies are ranked by total revenues for their respective fiscal years.","type":"Money","saveIn":"post_meta","importField":"f500_revenues","sortable":"sortable","order":"desc"}},{"key":"f500_profits","value":"14881","fieldMeta":{"franchiseId":2814606,"title":"Profits ($M)","altTitle":"Profits ($M)","description":"Net income after extraordinary charges for a company's respective fiscal year.","type":"Money","decimals":"1","saveIn":"post_meta","importField":"f500_profits","sortable":"sortable","order":"desc"}},{"key":"assets","value":"236495","fieldMeta":{"franchiseId":2814606,"title":"Assets ($M)","altTitle":"Assets ($M)","description":"Total assets on a company's fiscal year-end balance sheet.","type":"Money","saveIn":"post_meta","importField":"assets","sortable":"sortable","order":"desc"}},{"key":"totshequity","value":"74669","fieldMeta":{"franchiseId":2814606,"title":"Total Stockholder Equity ($M)","type":"Money","saveIn":"post_meta","importField":"totshequity"}}],"footnote":"","themeName":"half","change":[{"key":"revchange","value":"1.9","fieldMeta":{"franchiseId":2814606,"title":"Revenue Percent Change","altTitle":"Revenue Change","description":"Increase/decrease in revenues between the current and prior fiscal years.","type":"Percent","decimals":"1","saveIn":"post_meta","importField":"revchange","sortable":"sortable","order":"desc"}},{"key":"prftchange","value":"123.1","fieldMeta":{"franchiseId":2814606,"title":"Profits Percent Change","altTitle":"Profit Change","description":"Increase/decrease in profits between the current and prior fiscal years.","type":"Percent","decimals":"1","saveIn":"post_meta","importField":"prftchange","sortable":"sortable","order":"desc"}},{"key":null,"value":"","fieldMeta":false},{"key":null,"value":"","fieldMeta":false}],"changeHeader":"% change","valueHeader":"$ millions","showChange":true},"children":[]},{"name":"company-data-table","config":{"title":"Profit Ratios","tableIndex":1,"table":{"franchiseId":2814606,"title":"Profit Ratios","rows":[{"value":"Profit as % of Revenues"},{"value":"Profits as % of Assets"},{"value":"Profits as % of Stockholder Equity"}],"showValue":"show_value","pctChangeHeader":"% change"},"updated":"","data":[{"key":"prftpctsls","value":"2.8","fieldMeta":{"franchiseId":2814606,"title":"Profit as % of Revenues","type":"Percent","decimals":"1","saveIn":"post_meta","importField":"prftpctsls"}},{"key":"prftpctasts","value":"6.3","fieldMeta":{"franchiseId":2814606,"title":"Profits as % of Assets","type":"Percent","decimals":"1","saveIn":"post_meta","importField":"prftpctasts"}},{"key":"prftpctseqty","value":"19.9","fieldMeta":{"franchiseId":2814606,"title":"Profits as % of Stockholder Equity","type":"Percent","decimals":"1","saveIn":"post_meta","importField":"prftpctseqty"}}],"footnote":"","themeName":"half","change":[{"key":null,"value":"","fieldMeta":false},{"key":null,"value":"","fieldMeta":false},{"key":null,"value":"","fieldMeta":false}],"changeHeader":"% change","valueHeader":"","showChange":false},"children":[]},{"name":"company-data-table","config":{"title":"Earnings Per Share (Last Fiscal Year)","tableIndex":2,"table":{"franchiseId":2814606,"title":"Earnings Per Share (Last Fiscal Year)","rows":[{"value":"Earnings Per Share ($)"},{"value":"EPS % Change (from 2018)"},{"value":"EPS % Change (5 year annual rate)"},{"value":"EPS % Change (10 year annual rate)"}],"showValue":"show_value","pctChangeHeader":"% change"},"updated":"","data":[{"key":"eps","value":"5.19","fieldMeta":{"franchiseId":2814606,"title":"Earnings Per Share ($)","altTitle":"EPS","type":"Number","decimals":"2","saveIn":"post_meta","importField":"eps"}},{"key":"epschange","value":"129.6","fieldMeta":{"franchiseId":2814606,"title":"EPS % Change (from 2018)","type":"Percent","decimals":"1","saveIn":"post_meta","importField":"epschange"}},{"key":"eps5yr","value":"0.5","fieldMeta":{"franchiseId":2814606,"title":"EPS % Change (5 year annual rate)","type":"Percent","decimals":"1","saveIn":"post_meta","importField":"eps5yr"}},{"key":"eps10yr","value":"3.4","fieldMeta":{"franchiseId":2814606,"title":"EPS % Change (10 year annual rate)","type":"Percent","decimals":"1","saveIn":"post_meta","importField":"eps10yr"}}],"footnote":"","themeName":"half","change":[{"key":null,"value":"","fieldMeta":false},{"key":null,"value":"","fieldMeta":false},{"key":null,"value":"","fieldMeta":false},{"key":null,"value":"","fieldMeta":false}],"changeHeader":"% change","valueHeader":"","showChange":false},"children":[]},{"name":"company-data-table","config":{"title":"Total Return","tableIndex":3,"table":{"franchiseId":2814606,"title":"Total Return","rows":[{"value":"Total Return to Investors (2019)"},{"value":"Total Return to Investors (5 year, annualized)"},{"value":"Total Return to Investors (10 year, annualized)"}],"showValue":"show_value","pctChangeHeader":"% change"},"updated":"","data":[{"key":"totrti","value":"30.3","fieldMeta":{"franchiseId":2814606,"title":"Total Return to Investors (2019)","type":"Percent","decimals":"1","saveIn":"post_meta","importField":"totrti"}},{"key":"totrti5yr","value":"9.4","fieldMeta":{"franchiseId":2814606,"title":"Total Return to Investors (5 year, annualized)","type":"Percent","decimals":"1","saveIn":"post_meta","importField":"totrti5yr"}},{"key":"totrti10yr","value":"11","fieldMeta":{"franchiseId":2814606,"title":"Total Return to Investors (10 year, annualized)","type":"Percent","decimals":"1","saveIn":"post_meta","importField":"totrti10yr"}}],"footnote":"","themeName":"half","change":[{"key":null,"value":"","fieldMeta":false},{"key":null,"value":"","fieldMeta":false},{"key":null,"value":"","fieldMeta":false}],"changeHeader":"% change","valueHeader":"","showChange":false},"children":[]}]},{"name":"company-qlik","config":{"title":"Take a unique journey through the F500","eyebrowLabel":"fortune + qlik","description":"<p>We teamed up with Qlik, the Official Analytics Partner of the Fortune 500, to bring to life the shifting fortunes of iconic companies and sectors in an interactive data visualization.</p>\n","link":"https://qlik.fortune.com/"},"children":[{"name":"image","config":{"aspectRatio":0.6666666666666666,"attachmentId":2862622,"alt":"","caption":"","crops":[],"height":300,"imageSize":"qlik_2x3","lazyload":true,"lqipSrc":"https://content.fortune.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/qlik-2x3-1.gif?quality=60&resize=60,40","postId":0,"retina":true,"showCaption":false,"sources":[{"default":true,"transforms":{"resize":[181,296]}}],"sourceTags":[],"src":"https://content.fortune.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/qlik-2x3-1.gif","srcset":"https://content.fortune.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/qlik-2x3-1.gif?resize=362,592 0w,https://content.fortune.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/qlik-2x3-1.gif?resize=181,296 0w","url":"https://content.fortune.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/qlik-2x3-1.gif","useBasicImg":false,"usingDataFallback":false,"width":200,"fallbackImageUrl":"data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7","picture":false,"sizes":"100vw"},"children":[]},{"name":"image","config":{"aspectRatio":1.5,"attachmentId":2862623,"alt":"","caption":"","crops":[],"height":200,"imageSize":"qlik_3x2","lazyload":true,"lqipSrc":"https://content.fortune.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/qlik-3x2-1.gif?quality=60&resize=60,90","postId":0,"retina":true,"showCaption":false,"sources":[{"default":true,"transforms":{"resize":[181,121]}}],"sourceTags":[],"src":"https://content.fortune.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/qlik-3x2-1.gif","srcset":"https://content.fortune.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/qlik-3x2-1.gif?resize=362,242 0w,https://content.fortune.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/qlik-3x2-1.gif?resize=181,121 0w","url":"https://content.fortune.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/qlik-3x2-1.gif","useBasicImg":false,"usingDataFallback":false,"width":300,"fallbackImageUrl":"data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7","picture":false,"sizes":"100vw"},"children":[]}]},{"name":"company-rank-history-wrapper","config":{},"children":[{"name":"company-interactives-wrapper","config":{},"children":[{"name":"interactive","config":{"heading":"Walmart Rank History","interactiveUrl":"https://interactives.fortune.com/f500-dataviz-2020/rank_chart_single_co/index.html?guid=2255","refinitivUrl":"https://interactives.fortune.com/f500-dataviz-2020/rank_chart_single_co/index.html?ric","themeName":"company"},"children":[]}]}]},{"name":"company-historical","config":{"franchiseId":2814606,"companyId":2818204},"children":[]},{"name":"sidebar","config":{"themeName":"right"},"children":[{"name":"company-data-store-cta","config":{"buttonText":"Purchase Now","text":"Leads, insights, and financial data for the FORTUNE 500, FORTUNE 1000, and Global 500 companies.","url":"/data-store/"},"children":[]},{"name":"advertising-slot","config":{"align":"center","lazyload":true,"useDynamicChannel":false,"placementName":"RightRailFlex","slotId":"RightRailFlex0","targeting":{"placement_name":"RightRailFlex","index":1}},"children":[]}]}]},{"name":"company-ranking-list","config":{"heading":"Lists ranking","title":"Walmart"},"children":[{"name":"company-ranking-list-item","config":{"title":"Change the World","permalink":"https://fortune.com/company/walmart/change-the-world/","excerpt":"As we face unprecedented collective challenges, cooperation has become a business superpower.","year":"2020","color":"#f3eee2","logo":"","rank":"9","itemId":2818204},"children":[{"name":"image","config":{"aspectRatio":false,"attachmentId":2885302,"alt":"","caption":"","crops":[],"height":1920,"imageSize":"franchise-logo","lazyload":true,"lqipSrc":"data: image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7","postId":0,"retina":true,"showCaption":false,"sources":[{"default":true,"transforms":{"w":[115]},"descriptor":115}],"sourceTags":[],"src":"https://content.fortune.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/CTW20.change-the-world-Logo2-1.jpg","srcset":"https://content.fortune.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/CTW20.change-the-world-Logo2-1.jpg?w=230 230w,https://content.fortune.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/CTW20.change-the-world-Logo2-1.jpg?w=115 115w","url":"https://content.fortune.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/09/CTW20.change-the-world-Logo2-1.jpg","useBasicImg":false,"usingDataFallback":false,"width":2880,"fallbackImageUrl":"data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7","picture":false,"sizes":"115px"},"children":[]}]},{"name":"company-ranking-list-item","config":{"title":"Global 500","permalink":"https://fortune.com/company/walmart/global500/","excerpt":"This year's Global 500 generated $33.3 trillion in revenues and $2.1 trillion in profits.","year":"2020","color":"#ffe500","logo":"","rank":"1","itemId":2818204},"children":[{"name":"image","config":{"aspectRatio":false,"attachmentId":2864400,"alt":"G500-Featured Image-Logo-2020","caption":"","crops":[],"height":1920,"imageSize":"franchise-logo","lazyload":true,"lqipSrc":"data: image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7","postId":0,"retina":true,"showCaption":false,"sources":[{"default":true,"transforms":{"w":[115]},"descriptor":115}],"sourceTags":[],"src":"https://content.fortune.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/G500-Featured-Image-Logo-2020.jpg","srcset":"https://content.fortune.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/G500-Featured-Image-Logo-2020.jpg?w=230 230w,https://content.fortune.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/G500-Featured-Image-Logo-2020.jpg?w=115 115w","url":"https://content.fortune.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/08/G500-Featured-Image-Logo-2020.jpg","useBasicImg":false,"usingDataFallback":false,"width":2880,"fallbackImageUrl":"data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7","picture":false,"sizes":"115px"},"children":[]}]},{"name":"company-ranking-list-item","config":{"title":"Fortune 500","permalink":"https://fortune.com/company/walmart/fortune500/","excerpt":"This year's Fortune 500 marks the 66th running of the list.","year":"2020","color":"#000000","logo":"","rank":"1","itemId":2818204},"children":[{"name":"image","config":{"aspectRatio":false,"attachmentId":2817676,"alt":"F500-2020-Logo","caption":"","crops":[],"height":1920,"imageSize":"franchise-logo","lazyload":true,"lqipSrc":"data: image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7","postId":0,"retina":true,"showCaption":false,"sources":[{"default":true,"transforms":{"w":[115]},"descriptor":115}],"sourceTags":[],"src":"https://content.fortune.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/F500-2020-Logo.jpg","srcset":"https://content.fortune.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/F500-2020-Logo.jpg?w=230 230w,https://content.fortune.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/F500-2020-Logo.jpg?w=115 115w","url":"https://content.fortune.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/05/F500-2020-Logo.jpg","useBasicImg":false,"usingDataFallback":false,"width":2880,"fallbackImageUrl":"data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7","picture":false,"sizes":"115px"},"children":[]}]},{"name":"company-ranking-list-item","config":{"title":"World’s Most Admired Companies","permalink":"https://fortune.com/worlds-most-admired-companies/2020/walmart/","excerpt":"For an astounding 13th straight year, Apple claims the top spot in Fortune’s annual ranking of corporate reputation, based on a survey of almost 3,800 executives, directors, and analysts.","year":"2020","color":"#000000","logo":"","rank":"18","itemId":2753766},"children":[{"name":"image","config":{"aspectRatio":false,"attachmentId":2757757,"alt":"","caption":"","crops":[],"height":356,"imageSize":"franchise-logo","lazyload":true,"lqipSrc":"data: image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7","postId":0,"retina":true,"showCaption":false,"sources":[{"default":true,"transforms":{"w":[115]},"descriptor":115}],"sourceTags":[],"src":"https://content.fortune.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/wma_logo.jpg","srcset":"https://content.fortune.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/wma_logo.jpg?w=230 230w,https://content.fortune.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/wma_logo.jpg?w=115 115w","url":"https://content.fortune.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/wma_logo.jpg","useBasicImg":false,"usingDataFallback":false,"width":536,"fallbackImageUrl":"data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7","picture":false,"sizes":"115px"},"children":[]}]}]},{"name":"company-latest-news-wrapper","config":{"title":"Latest news for Walmart"},"children":[{"name":"advertising-slot","config":{"align":"center","lazyload":true,"useDynamicChannel":true,"placementName":"InStream","slotId":"InStream2","targeting":{"placement_name":"InStream","index":3}},"children":[]},{"name":"company-latest-news","config":{},"children":[{"name":"content-item","config":{"themeName":"company_latest_news","timeago":"","isNativoTout":false,"eyebrowSectionLabel":"Conferences","eyebrowSectionLink":"https://fortune.com/section/conferences/","eyebrowTagLabel":"Most Powerful Women","eyebrowTagLink":"https://fortune.com/tag/most-powerful-women/","title":"How Sam’s Club helped small businesses through COVID","permalink":"https://fortune.com/2020/10/01/sams-club-ceo-kathryn-mclay-small-business-most-powerful-women/","id":2894934,"excerpt":"The pandemic has sped up tech innovation at the warehouse retailer.","publishDateIso8601":"2020-10-01T16:53:55-04:00","type":"post"},"children":[{"name":"image","config":{"aspectRatio":0.5625,"attachmentId":2891872,"alt":"","caption":"","crops":[],"height":0,"imageSize":"full","lazyload":true,"lqipSrc":"data: image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7","postId":2894934,"retina":true,"showCaption":false,"sources":[],"sourceTags":[],"src":"","srcset":"","url":"","useBasicImg":false,"usingDataFallback":false,"width":0},"children":[]},{"name":"byline","config":{"link":"https://fortune.com/author/phil-wahba/","name":"Phil Wahba"},"children":[]}]},{"name":"content-item","config":{"themeName":"company_latest_news","timeago":"","isNativoTout":false,"eyebrowSectionLabel":"Retail","eyebrowSectionLink":"https://fortune.com/section/retail/","eyebrowTagLabel":"Walmart","eyebrowTagLink":"https://fortune.com/tag/walmart/","title":"Walmart unveils new store design inspired by Amazon and airports","permalink":"https://fortune.com/2020/09/30/walmart-new-store-design-app-online-pickup-amazon-airports/","id":2893828,"excerpt":"The discount chain wants people to use its Walmart app more and to be able to get in and out faster.","publishDateIso8601":"2020-09-30T11:41:27-04:00","type":"post"},"children":[{"name":"image","config":{"aspectRatio":0.5625,"attachmentId":2893884,"alt":"","caption":"","crops":[],"height":0,"imageSize":"full","lazyload":true,"lqipSrc":"data: image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7","postId":2893828,"retina":true,"showCaption":false,"sources":[],"sourceTags":[],"src":"","srcset":"","url":"","useBasicImg":false,"usingDataFallback":false,"width":0},"children":[]},{"name":"byline","config":{"link":"https://fortune.com/author/phil-wahba/","name":"Phil Wahba"},"children":[]}]},{"name":"content-item","config":{"themeName":"company_latest_news","timeago":"","isNativoTout":false,"eyebrowSectionLabel":"Conferences","eyebrowSectionLink":"https://fortune.com/section/conferences/","eyebrowTagLabel":"MPW Summit","eyebrowTagLink":"https://fortune.com/tag/mpw-summit/","title":"3 ways Walmart and Home Depot execs think retail will change for good","permalink":"https://fortune.com/2020/09/29/retail-coronavirus-pandemic-home-depot-walmart-execs-covid-19/","id":2893036,"excerpt":"We won't go back to pre-pandemic behavior, top execs from Walmart and Home Depot predicted at Fortune's virtual Most Powerful Women's conference Tuesday. ","publishDateIso8601":"2020-09-29T18:12:00-04:00","type":"post"},"children":[{"name":"image","config":{"aspectRatio":0.5625,"attachmentId":2890633,"alt":"","caption":"","crops":[],"height":0,"imageSize":"full","lazyload":true,"lqipSrc":"data: image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7","postId":2893036,"retina":true,"showCaption":false,"sources":[],"sourceTags":[],"src":"","srcset":"","url":"","useBasicImg":false,"usingDataFallback":false,"width":0},"children":[]},{"name":"byline","config":{"link":"https://fortune.com/author/anne-sraders/","name":"Anne Sraders"},"children":[]}]},{"name":"content-item","config":{"themeName":"company_latest_news","timeago":"","isNativoTout":false,"eyebrowSectionLabel":"Environment","eyebrowSectionLink":"https://fortune.com/section/environment/","eyebrowTagLabel":"Walmart","eyebrowTagLink":"https://fortune.com/tag/walmart/","title":"Walmart says it will eliminate emissions from global operations by 2040","permalink":"https://fortune.com/2020/09/21/walmart-emissions-global-reduction/","id":2888827,"excerpt":"The cuts, while substantial, will only cover its own operation's emissions—5% of the total. ","publishDateIso8601":"2020-09-21T06:52:56-04:00","type":"post"},"children":[{"name":"image","config":{"aspectRatio":0.5625,"attachmentId":2888833,"alt":"","caption":"","crops":[],"height":0,"imageSize":"full","lazyload":true,"lqipSrc":"data: image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7","postId":2888827,"retina":true,"showCaption":false,"sources":[],"sourceTags":[],"src":"","srcset":"","url":"","useBasicImg":false,"usingDataFallback":false,"width":0},"children":[]},{"name":"byline","config":{"link":"https://fortune.com/author/stephen-stapczynski/","name":"Stephen Stapczynski"},"children":[]},{"name":"byline","config":{"link":"https://fortune.com/author/akshat-rathi/","name":"Akshat Rathi"},"children":[]},{"name":"byline","config":{"link":"https://fortune.com/author/bloomberg/","name":"Bloomberg"},"children":[]}]},{"name":"content-item","config":{"themeName":"company_latest_news","timeago":"","isNativoTout":false,"eyebrowSectionLabel":"Retail","eyebrowSectionLink":"https://fortune.com/section/retail/","eyebrowTagLabel":"Food Waste","eyebrowTagLink":"https://fortune.com/tag/food-waste/","title":"Exclusive: Startup Apeel is launching ‘plastic-free’ cucumbers at Walmart to cut back on waste","permalink":"https://fortune.com/2020/09/21/apeel-cucumbers-walmart-plastic-food-waste/","id":2888394,"excerpt":"Apeel’s English cucumbers are coated in a plant-based material that extends shelf life without the need for single-use plastic.","publishDateIso8601":"2020-09-21T06:00:31-04:00","type":"post"},"children":[{"name":"image","config":{"aspectRatio":0.5625,"attachmentId":2888387,"alt":"","caption":"","crops":[],"height":0,"imageSize":"full","lazyload":true,"lqipSrc":"data: image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7","postId":2888394,"retina":true,"showCaption":false,"sources":[],"sourceTags":[],"src":"","srcset":"","url":"","useBasicImg":false,"usingDataFallback":false,"width":0},"children":[]},{"name":"byline","config":{"link":"https://fortune.com/author/beth-kowitt/","name":"Beth Kowitt"},"children":[]}]}]},{"name":"company-latest-videos","config":{"tags":["Walmart"],"title":"Walmart"},"children":[]},{"name":"sidebar","config":{"themeName":"right"},"children":[{"name":"advertising-slot","config":{"align":"center","lazyload":true,"useDynamicChannel":false,"placementName":"RightRailFlex","slotId":"RightRailFlex1","targeting":{"placement_name":"RightRailFlex","index":2}},"children":[]}]}]}]}}
```

What I want to extract is the `config` from `children of page` where the name is `company-information` and `description` from name `company-hero`. I read the articles and documentation, and I can do what I want if the document is not as nested. But I'm completely lost on how to extract those info that I'm looking from. This is the first time working on Mongodb for me to this extent. I had done something very basic before.

I tried

```
db.collection.find(
    {"page.children.3.children.2.name": {"$eq": "company-information"}}, 
    {"page.children.3.children.2": 1}
)
```

but got empty result

**Output**

There are about 1000 rows(? Not sure if I can call it rows). The part that I'm interested in is pulling the `page.children[3].children[2]` where the name is `company-information`. So the result should be the following:

```
"config": {
                "ceo": "C. Douglas McMillon",
                "companyType": "Public",
                "country": "U.S.",
                "employees": "2200000",
                "footnote": "Market value as of Sept. 15, 2020.",
                "headquarters": "Bentonville, Ark.",
                "industry": "General Merchandise",
                "marketValue": "389244",
                "profits": "14881",
                "revenues": "523964",
                "ticker": "WMT",
                "title": "Company information",
                "updated": "9/21/20",
                "website": "https://www.stock.walmart.com"
              }
```

Comment: Mongo is document-oriented database. When you query the database you get matching documents. Like the whole thing. If you need any transformations - calculated fields, parts of the documents, or any other ETL you need to use aggregation framework, map-reduce, or an application to manipulate the data.

Comment: @AlexBlex, I don't need any aggregation. I'm only trying to pull one part of the document which is nested. I just tried `db.collection.find({"page.children.3.children.2.name": {"$eq": "company-information"}},{"page.children.3.children.2": 1})` but got empty. Besides, the array size may be different for some companies and specifically setting children can return incorrect results. This is where I'm struggling a bit

Comment: @AlexBlex, I may be mistaken, but isn't that what projection is? I'm still learning but it seems like that's what I need, doesn't it?

Comment: There is a good reason why SO recommends to add your attempts to the question. Array indexes don't work this way. Please learn [dot-notation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#dot-notation) and for your specific query [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/index.html)

Comment: Projection indeed is used to request part of the document. Check if [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/) suffice. Don't confuse it with the $elemMatch in my previous comment. It's a different one.

Comment: Sorry mate, no luck. the $elemMatch in projection won't work for nested arrays. I'm afraid aggregation is unavoidable.

Comment: I can't for the life of me figure out the logic you want to apply. Could you post your expected result to give us a sporting chance.

Comment: So, mongodb is not really a good option to do things like what I wanted. I guess I should just pull all data and load it as JSON in python to parse to the data I need. I was hoping there'd be more elegant way to do it in mongodb. I'm still learning, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do (almost!) anything with an aggregate query. In your case I suggest using `$unwind` to convert the lists to onjects, then `$match` on your target field(s), `$project` to trim down the output, `$replaceRoot` to simplify the structure and `$limit` for good measure as there's actually 2 records that match your criteria.

https://mongoplayground.net/p/UsKeqA0aWYK

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$page.children"
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$page.children.children"
  },
  {
    "$match": {
      "page.children.children.name": "company-information"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "page.children.children.config": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$replaceRoot": {
      "newRoot": "$page.children.children"
    }
  },
  {
    "$limit": 1
  }
])
```

Comment: Wow! That's just amazing. This renewed my hope. Otherwise I was thinking based on some comments above, is this even worth learning. It's giving me so much think about and learn. Thank you